Lost printer drivers (Canon PIXMA MP210) with last software update
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.5 and a Canon PIXMA MP210 printer. After the last software update, I lost the printer's drivers.
I have the original CD with the setup for the printer, but when I try to run msetup4.exe to reinstall the drivers, I receive an error message:
An error occurred while loading the archive.

Tried canon_lbp_setup but received error 404: NOT FOUND.
I'm new to Ubuntu and I am having issues even navigating. Can someone tell me what to do to get my printer working again?
Beginning to think I need a new laptop and printer!

Need help. Canon does not support this model any longer. Linux 64 bit os.

According the answer the "An error occurred while loading the archive" indicates an attempt to run a Windows program on Linux. Therefore, assume msetup4.exe is the installer for Windows, which explains why it doesn't work under Ubuntu.

Canon MP210 printer: cannot install driver on Ubuntu 20.04 has an accepted answer which was to install the printer-driver-gutenprint package. Not sure if still applicable to Ubuntu 22.04, but suggest you try that.

Try this official Canon Pixma MP210 driver

@karel I downloaded the official driver. It contains two i386 deb packages that have dependencies which are not available on recent Ubuntu version. It may be possible to extract necessary files from the deb package and place them at appropriate locations, but I don't know enough about how printer drivers work to do so.

I added an answer. Please let us know if it does not work.

Karel - I downloaded MP210_debian.tar but am unsure what to do next.

Thanks! Archisman & Karel! Not sure which one, but I had shut down last night thinking I needed new printer. Started up today and deleted old printer and re-added MP210 again. It worked!!!

Download the combined Canon printer driver set (for "Linux 64 bit") from https://www.usa.canon.com/support/p/imageclass-mf4770n?tab=drivers#Z7_MQH8HIC0L88RB0AMD0F1Q42K25.
As of now, the latest version is v6.00.
Then, right click and extract the .tar.gz file.
Open a terminal in this folder and run sudo bash install.sh.
That should install the driver. Reboot and open printer settings, and add the printer.

I downloaded the linux-UFRII-drv-v600-us-02 when I right click I downloaded the fe to the terminal.

I could not extract the .tar.gz file.

When you right click, there should be an extract option. Is it not there?
